# How to insert records from one SQL Azure Instance table to the same table but in another instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Azure.

I am accessing and running DB Queries from within SSMS 2008.

I have 2 databases ie DB1 and DB2

I have a table in DB1 called "Orders" which is also in DB2 and is identical, but lacks the relevant orders for transfer. I do not want to copy the PKs across, these must be generated by DB2.Orders via in place identity PKs.

I believe the command looks something like:

```
Insert into DB2.Orders select * from DB1.Orders where status = "complete"
```

I would appreciate a confirmation of the correct SQL for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

sql azure doesn't support querying multiple databases together. However you can try this if you have a on prem server running using linked server features be selecting from db1 and then inserting into db2.

Answer (score -1):

Use Column name Instead Of *

```
Insert into DB2.schema.Orders values(columns...)
select columns from DB1.schema.Orders where status = "complete"
```

use Default schema **dbo** if you haven't create else..